# Boolean for #!@ keywords vim

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to do a syntax highlight regex in my _vimrc etc to highlight specific commands in comments for a visual cue.

The match should be `\s` followed by either a `#` or `!` then a `\s` or a `\S` then anything until the next `\s` followed by either a `#` or a `!` then a `\s`

eg the following lines should match with the bolded parts being what I want highlighted.

```
================================
```

" To run this use **`# <leader>R !`** to execute the command

**`#highlight #`** various items

"  another way is to **`# highlight #`** the line

```
=================================
```

So far I've tried

```
syn match myhelpComment "\s#\|!\(\s\|\S\)\+[#!]\s"
```

The regex above matches the `\s#` but not `\s!` below but doesn't match the text in between them.

```
syn match myhelpComment "\s#\|!\(\s\|\S\).*\s[#!]\s"
```

The regex above matches the bolded areas below which isn't quite right

**`" To run this use` # R ! `** to execute the command

**`"  another way is to # highlight #`** the line

This works in help.vim not in vim.vim and I have absolutely no idea why

```
syn match myhelpComment     "\s[:#!].\{-}\s[:#!]\s" --- Works in help.vim
```

But the following in vim.vim and

```
syn match myvimSpecial      "\s[:#!].\{-}\s[:#!]\s"
hi def link myvimSpecial        mySpecial
```

syncolor.vim

```
SynColor mySpecial  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=LightRed ctermbg=LightBlue gui=NONE guifg=LightRed guibg=#E6E600
```

Any suggestions on how to get the regex I want to work or why the one that works in help.vim works but doesn't work in vim.vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that works in help, but not Vim files is that your definition interferes with the default `syntax/vim.vim` definitions. As you'd like to match inside *comments*, your `:syn match` has to be `containedin=...` the corresponding group for comments:

```
syn match myvimSpecial      "\s[:#!].\{-}\s[:#!]\s" containedin=vimLineComment
```

Comment: Ah deferring looking at what `containedin`etc means has bittenme on the arse. Thanks muchly

Answer (score 0):

> The match should be \s followed by either a # or ! then a \s or a \S
>   then anything until the next \s followed by either a # or a ! then a
>   \s

I suppose you need something like this

```
/(^|\s)[!#][\s\S]\S+\s[#!]\s/
```

with multiline and global flag.